# A question related to Dirichlet's theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it possible for a natural number $k$ to exist such that for all primes $p$:
$$(p+1)k-1$$ is composite?

(i.e., can all $3k-1$, $4k-1$, $6k-1$, $8k-1$, $12k-1$, $14k-1$, $18k-1$, $20k-1$, $24k-1$, $30k-1$, $32k-1$, $38k-1$, $42k-1$, $44k-1$, $48k-1$, ... be composite?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seva proved that Dickson's conjecture implies there is no such $k$. 
One only needs a weak form of this conjecture. Such a weak form could potentially 
be much easier than for example the problem on 
infinitely Sophie Germain primes, as one does not need to know whether 
for two fixed forms, such as 
$f_1(n)=n$ and $f_2(n)=kn+(k-1)$ are
prime simulanteously, infinitely often, but just needs to know they produce one prime pair.

One can prove the following:
For every integer $k\geq 2$, there exists some power $k^r$ (where $r$ may depend on $k$)
such that there exists some prime $p$ with $k^r(p+1)-1$ also prime.
(This statement does not rule out the possibilty that some $k$ could exist.
for which all $k(+1)-1$ are composite, but it illustrates the view that some unconditional version
of a weak form of Dickson's-type conjectures could potentially solve the problem.

Proof: Results of Maynard-Tao 
(see e.g. James Maynard: Dense clusters of primes in subsets, https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.2593)
imply that two of the polynomials $f_i(t)=k^i t-1$ take prime values, simultaneously, infinitely often.
(Actually, we do not even need "infinitely often", we just need one such prime pair.)
With $p_1=k^i t-1, p_2=(p_1+1)k^{j-i}-1=k^j t-1$.
there exists a pair of primes $p, k^r (p+1)-1$. (We do not have good 
control over $r=j-i$ but that does not matter. Some upper bound on $r$ is possible in view of the 
quantitatve nature of Maynard's results).

Hence for $k^r$ the expression $k^r(p+1)-1$ is not always composite.

In view of quantitatve versions of Linnik's theorem on primes in progression,
or Dirichlet's theorem:
for every $p+1$ there are many values $k$ making $(p+1)k-1$ a prime. 
In this way one could sieve out the possible values for $k\leq N$ in an interval.
Probabilistically,
if one uses more than about $(\log N)^2$ linear forms, then
there should be very few $k \leq N$ left.
This is, as $(1- \frac{1}{\log N})^{(\log N)^2}\approx \frac{1}{N}$.

---

As Seve remarked that one can study $k=\frac{p+1}{q+1}$.
This topic has been extensively studied by Peter Elliott.
(Mathscinet: "Elliott" combined with "rationals" gives many papers).

In particular:
 The multiplicative group of rationals generated by the shifted primes, I.
by P.D.T.A. Elliott, Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik (1995), 463, page 169-216.
https://eudml.org/doc/153727

Here Elliott explicitly conjectures:
(Conjecture 1): Every positive rational $r$ has a representation $r=\frac{p+1}{q+1}$, $p$ and $q$ primes.

He comments that the strengthening has infinitely many representations is an analogue to Schinzel's hypothesis, and would follow from Dickson's conjectures. He studies the group of rationals generated by these shifted primes and achieves many deep results.

Answer (score 4):

Most certainly such $k$ do *not* exist. I am not sure whether there is a chance to prove this unconditionally, as even the situation with [Sophie Germain primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime) (which are primes $p$ such that $2p+1$ is also prime, related to the case $k=2$ of your question) is unclear.

Conditionally, the non-existence of $k$ is an immediate consequence of [Dickson's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture) stating that for a finite set of linear polynomials $f_1(n)=a_1n+b_1,\dotsc,f_m(n)=a_mn + b_m$ with integer coefficients and $a_1,\dotsc,a_m\ge 1$, there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ for which the values of these polynomials are all prime, unless the product $f_1(n)\dotsb f_m(n)$ has a fixed prime factor. For your problem, take $m=2$, $f_1(n)=n$, and $f_2(n)=kn+(k-1)$.

---

A nice reformulation of your question is as follows: is it true that every integer $k>0$ is representable as 
  $$ k = \frac{p+1}{q+1} $$
with $p$ and $q$ both prime? Dickson's conjecture implies that, in fact, any *rational* $k>0$ has *infinitely many* such representations: write $k=u/v$ and consider the polynomials $f_1(n)=un-1$ and $f_2(n)=vn-1$.

Comment: To me, "forms" implies homogeneous polynomials; I would say just "polynomials" here.

Comment: You just need to show that there is one prime in the list. It is not directly associated with Sophie-Germain

Comment: @Haran: you are right, I modified my answer appropriately.

Comment: I just though of the same before you did your edit. We don't need the whole of Dickson's conjecture for this problem. In fact, we just need to prove that in two arithmetic progressions, there will exist atleast one number n such that the nth number in both progressions is prime unless there is any congruence condition preventing it. We just need to show Dickson's conjecture for one value, not infinitely many, and only for k=2.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment on possible path to an unconditional proof.

If that were true you would have: $(p_n+1)k-1=a_nb_n$, where $1<a_n,b_n<(p_n+1)k$, that is, you would have $k=\frac {a_n b_n+1}{p_n+1}$ for every $n \in\mathbb N$ which implies $\frac{1}{k}=\frac{p_n+1}{a_n b_n+1}$ and that implies $$\sum_{l=1}^{+ \infty}(\frac{1}{k})^l=\sum_{l=1}^{+ \infty}(\frac{p_{l}+1}{a_l b_l+1})^l$$.

On the left hand side there is a rational number and I would bet that on the right hand side we have an irrational.

Comment: The idea looks really good but I am not sure whether the right hand side is irrational. Could you explain at least your intuition on why you expect it to be irrational?

Comment: @Haran Of course, I do not know how to prove that right hand side is irrational, but I would bet that it is because numerators contain all primes increased by 1 and then taken to the power of an index of a prime and divided by some number taken to the same power, if that were to be written in the form of a decimal expansion I do not believe that all would sum up to a rational number. I just do not know enough about laws that govern decimal expansions of primes taken to some power and divided by the same power of some number to turn this into a proof.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say this, but I just proved that the above is indirectly an unsolved problem. It is Dickson's Conjecture when $k=2$. I suggest to not work too much on this. Thank you for all the insights and ideas.

Comment: Instead of posting this answer, you should edit the original question statement.